# How to parse and encode Chinese Characters in Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: python, nlp, cjk

I want to train a really basic NLP model but using Chinese characters. Read_csv doesn't really work.

I was also wondering if there is any way to extract the different parts of the character, like for example, I would like to write an if function that works something like this:

```
x = input()

if x contains 女 [as part of the word]:
   female = 1
```

So if i typed in 媛， then female=1

The bottomline is to train a Naive Bayes model on Chinese characters. If anyone can direct me to resources that can help me to do this will be appreciated!

Thanks